# Magento Drop Ship Charges

Tags: dropshipping

When a customer chooses to order a product and ship it directly to the customer or multiple customers - we charge a drop ship fee of £3 per pack/deliver

Can this be done through magento?

Answer (score 0):

You will need either a custom payment method or a module that adds a surcharge or fee to existing payment methods. You have not specified which version of Magento you are using but there are extensions/modules available for Magento 1 and 2 in the Marketplace. Search for Magento Payment Fee or surcharge.